# How to set build name to triggering pipeline's branchname both under environments and pipeline run

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have two pipelines and two repos. One pipeline which builds a docker image and pushes it to a docker registry and one pipeline that takes a k8s configuration and deploys it to a k8s cluster.

I am also using three pipeline environments, dev, test and prod.

I would like to see both the version of the config (config-repo branchname) and the version of the application(application-repo branchname) in the environment status overview.

In my pipeline I have set the name to this:

```
name: $(Build.Sourcebranch)-$(RESOURCES.PIPELINE.BUILDPIPELINECI.sourceBranch)
```

My triggering pipeline is defined like this:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: buildpipelineCI 
    source: XXXweb-CI
    trigger: true
    branch: ${{variables['Build.SourceBranch']}}
```

The build name now becomes this:
[image]

If I add a script that dynamically changes the build name:

```
- task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Set build number'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        newbuildnumber=$(Build.SourceBranch)-$(RESOURCES.PIPELINE.BUILDPIPELINECI.sourceBranch)
        newbuildnumber=${newbuildnumber////_}
        echo $newbuildnumber
        echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$newbuildnumber"
```

Now it looks better, when the script has finished, the name of the build looks like this:
[image]

But my problem is that under environments I still see the first text:
[image]

How can I see the branchname/version of the triggering repo under environments?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: It was a perfect answer, 10/10! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can use the resource variable to set the buildnumber and show the updated name in environment.

Here are the following two limitations:

1. The variable：**$(RESOURCES.PIPELINE.BUILDPIPELINECI.sourceBranch)** will expand at runtime and the **name** field will expand at compile time. So it can not directly get the value from Resource Variable.
2. When you use logging command:  `echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$newbuildnumber"` to update the build number. The value will not update in the environment. It will show the original Pipeline build name. This is a known issue in Azure DevOps. Refer to this ticket: [Build Number Not Updated In Environments View If Changed In Pipeline](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-Number-Not-Updated-In-Environments/10220047)

For a workaround, we can use two pipelines to achieve the goal. One is used to get the value of varaibel:**$(RESOURCES.PIPELINE.BUILDPIPELINECI.sourceBranch)** and trigger the  other pipeline. The other pipeline will use parameter to get the value and set the build number.

Here is an example:

Pipeline 1 to get the variable name and trigger the pipeline 2:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: buildpipelineCI 
    source: test1025
    trigger: true
    branch: ${{variables['Build.SourceBranch']}}
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $token = "$(pat)"
      $branchvalue = "$(RESOURCES.PIPELINE.BUILDPIPELINECI.sourceBranch)"
      $newvalue = $branchvalue.Replace('/','_')
      echo $newvalue
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineID}}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
      
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
      $JSON = "
      {
        
      
      
        `"resources`": {
          `"repositories`": {
            `"self`": {
              `"refName`": `"refs/heads/main`"
            }
          }
        },
        `"templateParameters`": {
          `"test`":`"$($newvalue)`"
         },
      
      
      
      }"
      
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

Pipeline 2: set parameter to accept the variable value and set the build number:

```
name: $(Build.Sourcebranch)-${{parameters.test}}

parameters:
  - name: test
    type: string
    default: test1


pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
    environment: 
      name: 'smarthotel-dev'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world
```

Result:

Pipeline Run:

[image]

Environment:

[image]